# R: create a vector based on a list

Tags: r

I have the following list called `m1`:

```
> m1
[[1]]
[1] 36 37 38

[[2]]
[1] 34 35

[[3]]
[1] 30 31 32 33

[[4]]
[1] 24 25 26 27 28 29

[[5]]
[1] 20 21 22 23

[[6]]
[1] 14 15 16 17 18 19

[[7]]
[1] 11 12 13

[[8]]
[1]  7  8  9 10

[[9]]
[1] 5 6

[[10]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[11]]
integer(0)
```

I would like to create a vector based on this list, which has the value 1 at positions 36, 37, and 38; the value 2 at positions 34 and 35, etc. The final output should be:

`vector_1 <- c(10, 10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1)`

How can I accomplish this in R?

EDIT:

Thanks to a comment below:

```
> rep(length(m1):1, sapply(m1, length))
 [1] 11 11 11 10 10  9  9  9  9  8  8  8  8  8  8  7  7  7  7  6  6  6  6  6  6  5  5  5  4
[30]  4  4  4  3  3  2  2  2  2
```

That doesn't quite give me what I want, but it's definitely on the right track!

Comment: @agenis Why not post as an answer?

Comment: well @statssorceress it would help if you told us wether the data you posted is exactly your data or something alike. And if so, how different can it get? can you have empty elements in the middle of the list? can it jump numbers? etc. thanks

Comment: Hi @agenis, it's exactly as above. I copied and pasted.

Comment: sorry I was wrong, I was fooled by the symmetry of the lengths and interpreted your need the other way round.. good job to @Ryan Runge

Comment: @agenis - thanks, that was an interesting challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
rev(unlist(sapply(1:length(m1), function(x) rep(x,length(m1[[x]])))))

#or even better, @snoram's edited version of this:

rev(rep(seq_along(m1), sapply(m1, length)))
```

Output:

```
[1] 10 10 10 10  9  9  8  8  8  8  7  7  7  6  6  6  6  6  6  5  5  5  5  4
[25]  4  4  4  4  4  3  3  3  3  2  2  1  1  1
```

Sample data:

```
m1 <- list(36:38,34:35,30:33,24:29,20:23,
           14:19,11:13,7:10,5:6,1:4)
names(m1) <- 1:10
```

Answer (score 3):

This should handle cases with empty entries and non-sequential entries....

```
m1 <- list(c(7,4,5), c(2,10,9), c(1,3,6,8), integer())
# [[1]]
# [1] 7 4 5
# 
# [[2]]
# [1]  2 10  9
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 1 3 6 8
# 
# [[4]]
# integer(0)

rep(seq_along(m1), sapply(m1, length))[order(unlist(m1))]
#[1] 3 2 3 1 1 3 1 3 2 2
```

Comment: `rep(seq_along(m1), lengths(m1))[order(unlist(m1))]`

Answer (score 2):

This solution should work for more general cases too even if the elements inside `m1` are not in a specific order

```
#DATA
m1 = list(36:38, 34:35, 30:33, 24:29, 20:23,
          14:19, 11:13, 7:10, 5:6, 1:4, integer(0))

#Extract the maximum element in m1
mymax = max(unlist(m1))
#Go through m1 using index and replace respective indices in the position
#defined by the elements of m1, otherwise make the elements zero 
Reduce("+", lapply(1:length(m1), function(i)
    replace(rep(0, mymax), m1[[i]], i)))
# [1] 10 10 10 10  9  9  8  8  8  8  7  7  7  6  6  6  6  6  6  5  5  5  5
#[24]  4  4  4  4  4  4  3  3  3  3  2  2  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a straightforward base-R solution:

```
# data
m1 <- list(36:38, 34:35, 30:33, 24:29, 20:23, 14:19, 11:13, 7:10, 5:6, 1:4, integer(0))

# Count length, and repeat each number in 1:11 accordingly
rev(rep(1:11, sapply(m1, length)))
 [1] 10 10 10 10  9  9  8  8  8  8  7  7  7  6  6  6  6  6  6  5  5  5  5  4  4  4  4  4  4  3  3  3
[33]  3  2  2  1  1  1
```

**Edit**: 
A more generalisable answer would be:

```
rev(rep(seq_along(m1), sapply(m1, length)))
```

Comment: Nice, same answer as mine, but even more concise. +1

Comment: I wasn't aware of your answer until after writing up mine. However, your solution is more complete than my original solution because "magic number" `1:11` fails to generalize, I think `seq_along(m1)` is more appropriate.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. I started with 1:length(m1), but seq_along(m1) is also an improvement to that. I'm putting your edits in the selected answer so you can share credit. These are good edits.